# How to concatenate many more columns to one column with list format?

Tags: python, pandas

I need convert array to Dataframe, the default method like that:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

out:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   1   2   3
2   1   2   3
```

but, I want to the format, like:

```
    0
0   [1, 2, 3]
1   [1, 2, 3]
2   [1, 2, 3]
```

just one column.

EDIT: the other situation,

```
lst = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `array` scenario, use `apply` with `list` and `to_frame`

```
lst = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])

pd.DataFrame(lst).apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1).to_frame()
```

```
           0
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [1, 2, 3]
2  [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You may initialize a single column:

```
In [279]: pd.DataFrame({0: lst})                                                                                
Out[279]: 
           0
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [1, 2, 3]
2  [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: thanks, I modified code, like: lst = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]), and how? please.

Answer (score 1):

make a series and then a dataframe of that

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(lst))

           0
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [1, 2, 3]
2  [1, 2, 3]
```